# С# имитация нажатия мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго дня, взялся недавно за проект. Постигаю проблемы коммерческой разработки, так сказать) Встретился вот с такой проблемой. Нужно запомнить кординаты мыши, когда была нажата LMB, но вот проблема, в WPF событиях `OnMouseButtonDown` отслеживает только нажатия по форме, а мне надо, чтобы клики засчитывались не зависимо от того, где я нажал.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду нажатия за пределами вашего окна?

Comment: Да, вы правы(.)

Comment: Подозреваю что нужно подписатся на соответствующее событие WinApi и если был клик мышки то запоминать его координаты